Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_bcrypt_gensalt
I am working on a cpp project and I am trying to build project with following command in build folder
cmake ..
make

and during linking process I am getting error
[ 96%] Linking CXX shared library libsdkrest.dylib
ld: warning: -s is obsolete
ld: warning: -undefined error is deprecated
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_bcrypt_gensalt", referenced from:
      BCrypt::generateSalt() in SDKRESTAPI.cc.o
"_ber_free", referenced from:
  _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
"_idn2_check_version", referenced from:
      _Curl_idn_decode in libcurl.a[68](libcurl_la-idn.o)
      _Curl_idnconvert_hostname in libcurl.a[68](libcurl_la-idn.o)
  "_idn2_free", referenced from:
      _Curl_idn_decode in libcurl.a[68](libcurl_la-idn.o)
      _Curl_free_idnconverted_hostname in libcurl.a[68](libcurl_la-idn.o)
  "_idn2_lookup_ul", referenced from:
      _Curl_idn_decode in libcurl.a[68](libcurl_la-idn.o)
      _Curl_idn_decode in libcurl.a[68](libcurl_la-idn.o)
      _Curl_idnconvert_hostname in libcurl.a[68](libcurl_la-idn.o)
      _Curl_idnconvert_hostname in libcurl.a[68](libcurl_la-idn.o)
  "_ldap_err2string", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_first_attribute", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_first_entry", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_free_urldesc", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_get_dn", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_get_values_len", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_init", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_memfree", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_msgfree", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_next_attribute", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_next_entry", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_search_s", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_set_option", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_simple_bind_s", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_unbind_s", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_url_parse", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_ldap_value_free_len", referenced from:
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
      _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o)
  "_nghttp2_http2_strerror", referenced from:
      _http2_handle_stream_close in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_is_fatal", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _h2_session_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _h2_session_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_frame_recv in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_frame_recv in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_option_del", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_option_new", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_option_set_no_rfc9113_leading_and_trailing_ws_validation", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_pack_settings_payload", referenced from:
      _Curl_http2_request_upgrade in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_priority_spec_init", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _h2_session_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_callbacks_del", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_callbacks_new", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_error_callback", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_begin_headers_callback", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_data_chunk_recv_callback", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_frame_recv_callback", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_header_callback", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_stream_close_callback", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_send_callback", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_check_request_allowed", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_query in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _h2_process_pending_input in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_client_new2", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_del", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_destroy in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_close in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _http2_cfilter_add in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _Curl_http2_switch_at in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_get_remote_settings", referenced from:
      _on_frame_recv in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_frame_recv in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_get_remote_window_size", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_get_select_socks in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_get_stream_remote_window_size", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_get_select_socks in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_get_stream_user_data", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_cntrl in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _data_source_read_callback in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_frame_recv in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_data_chunk_recv in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_stream_close in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_begin_headers in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_header in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      ...
  "_nghttp2_session_mem_recv", referenced from:
      _h2_process_pending_input in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_resume_data", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_cntrl in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_send", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_cntrl in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_keep_alive in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _h2_session_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_set_local_window_size", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_cntrl in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_set_stream_user_data", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_cntrl in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_frame_recv in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_stream_close in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_upgrade2", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_want_read", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_recv in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _h2_process_pending_input in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _should_close_session in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_session_want_write", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_get_select_socks in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_recv in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_cntrl in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_cntrl in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _h2_process_pending_input in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _should_close_session in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      ...
  "_nghttp2_strerror", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_cntrl in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_keep_alive in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_keep_alive in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _h2_process_pending_input in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      ...
  "_nghttp2_submit_ping", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_keep_alive in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_submit_priority", referenced from:
      _h2_session_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_submit_request", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_send in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_submit_rst_stream", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_cntrl in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_frame_recv in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_frame_recv in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
      _on_header in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_submit_settings", referenced from:
      _cf_h2_ctx_init in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
  "_nghttp2_version", referenced from:
      _Curl_http2_ver in libcurl.a[61](libcurl_la-http2.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It seems that error is related libcurl not configured and build properly but I used below config
ExternalProject_Add(curl
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${CURL_DIR}
    INSTALL_DIR ${THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_DIR}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${CURL_DIR}/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR> --with-openssl --disable-openssl-auto-load-config --without-zlib --disable-ldap --without-nghttp2 --without-brotli --without-librtmp --without-libidn2 --host=arm-apple-darwin23
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install)
ExternalProject_Add_Step(curl
    fixinstallname
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL} -id "@rpath/libcurl.4.dylib" <INSTALL_DIR>/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
    DEPENDEES install)
add_dependencies(curl openssl zlib)

Here I am building curl lib without ldap and http2 but even after that is is giving error related to it. Please someone help me to identify the issue.
Edit: More Detail
Due to comments of Tsyvarev I checked bcrypt lib for the issue, link of the lib is bellow
https://github.com/trusch/libbcrypt
and I found out that there are some modifications are done in this lib by previous developer, the previous developer added the below code in Bcrypt.hpp file's public: section to be able call genrateSalt method
static std::string generateSalt() {
            char salt[BCRYPT_HASHSIZE];
            int ret = bcrypt_gensalt(10, salt);
            if(ret != 0)throw std::runtime_error{"bcrypt: can not generate salt"};
            std::string saltString = salt;
            return saltString;
        }

and config use for building libbcrypt is
ExternalProject_Add(bcrypt
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${BCRYPT_DIR}
    INSTALL_DIR ${THIRDPARTY_INSTALL_DIR}
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>)

Edit 2: cmake code for Linking
target_link_libraries(
    sdkrest
    base64
    utility
    ${JSONCPP_LIBRARY}
    ${CURL_LIBRARY}
    ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
    ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} 
    ${DATADOG_LIBRARY}
    ${LEVELDB_LIBRARY}
    ${SHAMIR_LIBRARY}
    ${THRIFT_LIBRARY}
    ${SDKLO_LIBRARY}
    ${OPENTRACING_LIBRARY}
    Threads::Threads
    ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
)

I also tried to add in above
${CRYPT_LIB} 
${LDAP_LIB} 
${IDN2_LIB}

with below code
find_library(CRYPT_LIB crypt)
find_library(LDAP_LIB ldap)
find_library(IDN2_LIB idn2)

# Check if the libraries were found
if(NOT CRYPT_LIB)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "libcrypt not found")
endif()
if(NOT LDAP_LIB)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "libldap not found")
endif()
if(NOT IDN2_LIB)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "libidn2 not found")
endif()

but getting error
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:183 (message):
  libcrypt not found



libcurl is built and configured properly. It is the library libsdkrest which uses libcurl forgot to link with libbcrypt library. (Linking with C++ version of libbcrypt library is not sufficient.)

Is there anything that I can do to fix issue ?

You need to fix your project to link with the proper libraries. The code which you show isn't sufficient to add more detailed receipts.

None line of the (CMake) code you show links with bcrypt library. Hint: Linkage is performed with target_link_libraries command.

Thanks @Tsyvarev I added more info please let me know If I have to provide more info

Your target_link_libraries call doesn't link with bcrypt. That is why you got the error. For fix that error you need to link with bcrypt. Oh, this is what I said in my previous comments.

In other words, add bcrypt as a line in your target_link_libraries( ... ) block.

Thanks for the help i linked the bcrypt lib and error related to it is now fixed but other error are not fixed. so now in error only _bcrypt_gensalt", referenced from:       BCrypt::generateSalt() in SDKRESTAPI.cc.o is removed but all other is there. Any comments on why I am getting error "_ber_free", referenced from:   _ldap_do in libcurl.a[74](libcurl_la-ldap.o) ?

Have you tried to google for undefined symbols and find out which library defines them. E.g. the ber_free function is defined in by liblber library, the idn2_check_version function is defined in libidn2 library. Make sure to place linkage with those libraries after the libraries which consumes given symbols.

I am not using ber_free and it's part of lib curl the project is building/running  fine on linux but I am getting issues on mac with m1 chip it was working fine on old mac with intel chip

You use static library libcurl.a. A library of such kind doesn't contain references to other libraries, needed for its functionality. It is your responsibility (as a developer of the project which links with libcurl.a) to link all libraries which are required for libcurl.a.
